# how to make a selected value in spinner as a default one for next session in android

Tags: android

I am working on an android project and I am using a spinner which is populated manually.
For example if, in the spinner I have the following items:

select

Category 1

Category 2

Category 3

Initially the spinner value is select now i selected category 2 
How would I programmatically make Category 2 as the default value for next session(opening the app next time).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the first session you save the selected index in a SharedPreferences:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("srIndex",spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

And in the second session you read the saved index and set it to the spinner:

```
spinner.setSelection(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("srIndex",0));
```

Comment: could you please tell me in detail about srIndex and where i add this code, is it after spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

Comment: Call the first line when the app is closed (onPause / onStop). And the second line after initializing the Spinner (after setAdapter). "srIndex" is the name of the saved index.

Comment: any where we can close the app, that means i have to add that in every class in my project, could you please clarify me

Answer (score 0):

If you know the position of "Category 2" you can do the item below. You can get the index from the adapter.

```
spinner.setSelection(indexOfCategory2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to save the index of selected category and every time activity is loaded retrieve the index from SharedPreferences and set selection

```
Spinner.setSelection(index);
```

If you not aware of SharedPreferences you can refer to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)